# C++17 code not compiling on Travis with Clang-6.0

Tags: c++, clang, travis-ci, c++17

I've been working on migrating our codebase to C++17, and have now got it working with both g++ and clang, locally.

However, I'm experiencing compilation failures on Travis with both Clang 6.0, and Clang 5.0, which both supposedly have C++17 support.

Furthermore, compiling the same code on my machine, with Clang 6.0, succeeds.

The relevant code that is failing is returning a tuple by brace initialization, for example:

```
return {str.str(), key};
```

The specific error message I'm getting is:

```
/home/travis/build/turtlecoin/turtlecoin/src/Mnemonics/Mnemonics.cpp:51:20: error: chosen constructor is explicit in copy-initialization
            return {str.str(), key};
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/tuple:539:19: note: explicit constructor declared here
        constexpr tuple(_U1&& __a1, _U2&& __a2)
```

It appears to be using clang-6.0 as expected:

```
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang-6.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang-6.0 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++-6.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++-6.0 -- works
```

My local clang which is working fine:

```
clang version 6.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_601/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

Is this an issue with Travis? Clang? My code?

If it helps, the full build log is here:
https://travis-ci.org/turtlecoin/turtlecoin/jobs/437857481

edit: Forgot to mention - I am using the flags to enable C++17 mode, in my CMakeLists:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

Thank you.

Comment: See the example in the __Notes__ and __Defect Reports__ here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple  Looks like there is a also a work around.

Comment: @RichardCritten Of course I could use std::make_tuple() - This is what I was using before. However, I find the new syntax much more readable, and would like to take advantage of the C++17 features. I'm not great at parsing the C++ reports, but it looks like they are revising the C++11 standard with these new features, not the C++17 standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler and the standard library you are using are two connected, but not identical things.

Odds are your local standard library is different than the remote one.

It could be a libc++ vs libstdc++ standard library different, or maybe the Travis standard library is somehow out of data.

One of the new features in C++17 is conditionally explicit tuple construction.  So a slightly out of date/less conformant std library would give you exactly that error.

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick. I needed to install libstdc++-7-dev.

Answer (score 2):

As @Yakk - Adam Nevraumont said, this was caused by the libstdc++ not being up to date. We can solve this by installing a newer one.

Since Travis uses Ubuntu 14.04, we can get `libstdc++-7-dev` from the `ubuntu-toolchain-r-test` PPA.

In your travis config:

```
- os: linux
    compiler: clang
    addons:
      apt:
        sources:
        - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
        - llvm-toolchain-trusty-6.0
        packages: 
          - clang-6.0
          - libstdc++-7-dev
    env:
    - MATRIX_EVAL="CC=clang-6.0 && CXX=clang++-6.0"
```

Comment: Adding `- libstdc++-7-dev" under `packages:` fixed this for me. Cheers!